# Converting IntPtr to Audio Data Array

Tags: c#, pointers, unity-game-engine, audio, webrtc

I've been trying to implement a `WebRTC` audio/video communication on Unity. So far, with the help of [**this blog post**](http://hammmm.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/04/23/233814) (and Google Translate) and the very few examples on the internet, I've managed to make quite a lot work on Unity using the `WebRTC` [**Unity Plugin**](https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/+/master/examples/unityplugin/).

But now I'm stuck. The great Unity sample project by **`mhama`** sadly doesn't have an example of how to convert the data I get from the native code to something that can be used as audio data in Unity.

---

**The info I get from the callback is this**

```
(IntPtr data, int bitsPerSample, int sampleRate, int numberOfChannels, int numberOfFrames)
```

---

**That data in the native code is declared as**

```
const void* audio_data
```

I know that to create an Audio Clip that Unity can use play some sound, I need a `float` array with sample values from `-1 to 1`. How do I go from that `IntPtr` data and all that extra info to that `float` array, is something I have no idea how to do.

[**Here's the sample I'm using as a base**](https://github.com/mhama/WebRtcUnityPluginSample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this without unsafe code. You'll need to make sure your project has unsafe code allowed.

```
// allocate the float arrays for the output. 
// numberOfChannels x numberOfFrames
float[][] output = new float[numberOfChannels][];
for (int ch = 0 ; ch < numberOfChannels; ++ch)
    output[ch] = new float[numberOfFrames];

// scaling factor for converting signed PCM into float (-1.0 to 1.0)
const double scaleIntToFloat = 1.0/0x7fffffff;

unsafe 
{ 
    // obtain a pointer to the raw PCM audio data.
    byte *ptr = (byte *)data.ToPointer();

    for (int frame = 0 ; frame < numberOfFrames; ++frame)
    {
        for (int ch = 0 ; ch < numberOfChannels; ++ch)
        {
            switch (bitsPerSample)
            {
                case 32:
                   // shift 4 bytes into the integer value
                   int intValue = *ptr++ << 24 & *ptr++ << 16 &
                                  *ptr++ << 8 & *ptr++;
                   // scale the int to float and store.
                   output[ch][frame] = scaleIntToFloat * intValue;
                   break;
                case 16: 
                   // shift 2 bytes into the integer value. Note:
                   // shifting into the upper 16 bits to simplify things,
                   // e.g. multiply by the same scaling factor.
                   int intValue = *ptr++ << 24 & *ptr++ << 16; 
                   output[ch][frame] = scaleIntToFloat * intValue;
                   break;
                case 24:
                   ...
                case 8:
                   // not 8-bit is typically unsigned. Google it if
                   // you need to.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the other conversions by searching this site for conversion of PCM to float. Also, depending on your circumstances, you might need a different endianness. If so, shift into the `intValue` in a different byte order.

Comment: It worked perfectly well(aside from the audio seemingly being lower than it should, but I think I can work with that). Thank you so much.